# AutoMapper treats known class instance as `Object`

Tags: automapper

I have a test that checks that objects match after conversion but automapper 10 has started saying I am missing a map from Object -> ExistingClass when the source object is defined.

Not an easy one to google, ahs anyone seen this before?

```cs
//maps defined elsewhere and checked
CreateMap<AnimalDBO, AnimalDTO>(MemberList.Destination)
CreateMap<AnimalDTO, AnimalBase>(MemberList.Destination)

var animal = new AnimalDBO
{
    Ear_Tag = "IE301228071641"
};

82: AnimalDTO dto = mapper.Map<AnimalDTO>(animal);
83: var ab = mapper.Map<AnimalBase>(dto);  //Automapper errors with Object -> AnimalBase
```

The object error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
    
    Mapping types:
    Object -> AnimalBase
    System.Object -> HukNetCore.Animal.Domain.AnimalBase
  Stack Trace: 
    lambda_method(Closure , Object , AnimalBase , ResolutionContext )
    EarTagTests.StringToEarTagIE() line 83
```

I've tracked the error down to this method

```
private TDestination MapCore<TSource, TDestination>(
            TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context, Type sourceType = null, Type destinationType = null, IMemberMap memberMap = null)
        {
            return ConfigurationProvider.GetExecutionPlan<TSource, TDestination>(MapRequest())(source, destination, context);
            MapRequest MapRequest()
            {
                var runtimeTypes = new TypePair(source?.GetType() ?? sourceType ?? typeof(TSource), destination?.GetType() ?? destinationType ?? typeof(TDestination));
                var requestedTypes = new TypePair(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination));
                return new MapRequest(requestedTypes, runtimeTypes, memberMap);
            }
        }
```

And these are the object created in that method

```
new TypePair(source?.GetType() ?? sourceType ?? typeof(TSource), destination?.GetType() ?? destinationType ?? typeof(TDestination))
"AnimalDTO", "AnimalBase"
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    DestinationType: {Name = "AnimalBase" FullName = "Animal.Domain.AnimalBase"}
    IsGeneric: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    SourceType: {Name = "AnimalDTO" FullName = "Animal.Domain.DTO.AnimalDTO"}
    SourceType: {Name = "AnimalDTO" FullName = "Animal.Domain.DTO.AnimalDTO"}
error CS0726: ':' is not a valid format specifier
new TypePair(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination))
"Object", "AnimalBase"
    ContainsGenericParameters: false
    DestinationType: {Name = "AnimalBase" FullName = "Animal.Domain.AnimalBase"}
    IsGeneric: false
    IsGenericTypeDefinition: false
    SourceType: {Name = "Object" FullName = "System.Object"}
```

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: This is the same issue as https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3542 that was not resolved :(

Comment: No, it looks like an usage error. The MyGet build will give you a better error message.

Comment: I'm getting a different error after updating.

`System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'AutoMapper.Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression' from assembly 'AutoMapper, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005'`

`<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="10.1.2-alpha.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />`

Comment: when calling services.AddAutoMapper(refs);

Comment: This is probably a red herring (misleading) but taking out the DependencyInjection and manually adding the profiles I don't get that error with 10.1.2-alpha.0.3. I can go back to 10.1.1 without DI and it works, use the DI and I get that error

Comment: Then the AM DI is not configured properly.

Comment: I've updated the post. It returns object for source on `var requestedTypes = new TypePair(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination));`

Comment: That has nothing to do with your error. You need to fix your AM DI config.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Lucian,

In my case it turned out to be that when the DI was being set up I was not loading an assembly into memory before calling `services.AddAutoMapper(refs);`.

Check your ref list and check all the dlls your expect are loaded